# Mismatched entity and/or field definitions for comment field

Tags: 8, entities, configuration

I get this message

> Entity/field definitions
> Mismatched entity and/or field definitions
> The following changes were detected in the entity type and field definitions.
>
> Comment
> The Entity type field needs to be updated.
> The Comment field name field needs to be updated.

I tried quite a lot of things including running `drush entup`  (apparently depreciated) and adding some lines on entity update to index.php. Nothing fixed the issue.

I don't really use comments on my site, but I would like to resolve this.

How can I fix this error?